# Extract data from several files

Tags: php, mysql, xml

Sorry that I was not clear enough earlier. I will try to give as much info as possible this time.

I have 8000 `XML` files in a folder that I extract data from and populate my database in MySQL via php. The problem is that I cannot insert more than 4,000 records at a time.

Some members suggested me to split the files between several folders.  With that method, I should be able to insert the data from all the 8,000 files without any problem.

Since I use `opendir` and `readdir` to open and read 8,000 files from that unique folder, if I split the files between two folders, should I still stick to `opendir` and `readdir`?

If yes, how should i write this in php when I have to do that for more than one folder? Is there any better way to read and extract the data from the 8,000 `XML` files at a time without spliting them into several folders?

Thanks again for your time

Answer (score 1):

If the limit is in the amount of records, how does the number of files per folder have anything to do with it? You can read a folder, collect records to insert and build a statement from the. Then if you reach 4000, insert your statement, and continue by starting a new statement with the rest of the files.

Comment: I don't know why I can't read more than 4000 files at a time. But every time I run the program, I have only 4000 records inserted into my database. I tried so many time. Following some suggestions, I even changed max_execution_time = 30  to max_execution_time = 60 to max_input_time = 600 and memory_limit = 128M to memory_limit = 512M. Those changes help me gained about 10 records, but no more than that. I still don't know what can be the problem.

Comment: @T3000 Do you have to populate the DB with HTTP request(s)?

Answer (score 0):

1) Get a list of all the files.
2) iterate over the list open a file
3) extract the XML nodes and execute sql statements
4) close the file
5) continue until you are done

Answer (score 0):

```
//Parse XML for each file here
function parseXML($file) {

}

//Loops through each file in directory
if ($handle = opendir('directoryWithXMLFiles')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            parseXML($file);
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

An alternative method would be to transform the data into a CSV format.  Then use the MySQL data load syntax. If you are more familiar with another language you could avoid using PHP.

i.e.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/importfile.csv' 
INTO TABLE test_table 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
(field1, filed2, field3);
```

http://support.modwest.com/content/6/253/en/how-do-i-import-delimited-data-into-mysql.html